# Force Google Chrome to load background pages

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I open links via context menu item **Open in background** but background pages begin to load only when tab is selected.
Is it possible to force *Google Chrome for Android* to load pages which are opened in background?

Comment: I didn't find anything related on `chrome://flags`, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: so do I with same result =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible, because it makes a little sense. Chrome is a multi-process browser and it uses dedicated processes (in Android terms, Services) for rendering pages. On Android, processes working in background are usually aggressively killed by the system in order to free memory for foreground processes. It makes no sense to do loading of background pages as a renderer in background will most likely be killed soon, it will be just a waste of network and CPU resources. So Chrome just creates a placeholders for background tabs and only "fills" them when the user switches to them.

Comment: Maybe it makes a little sense from perspective of OS. But for user it's good. It would be nice to have possibility to read current page and at same time download background page. At time when you read current page all background page will be ready. User happy. I thought it is obvious. So, I assume it's not possible, because of system design flaw.

Comment: At least Chrome does DNS prefetching for hosts from the links on your current page. As DNS caches are browser- or even OS-wide, this works well.